# "this" in java is not referring to current object's members. But, rather it's depending upon the point of access. Why?

Tags: java

I have three simple classes (BaseClass and ExtendedClass : which extends from the first one. And TestBaseExtendedClasses to test the classes).

As per my understanding "this" should access the object instance, inside which the code is running and it's member variables. 
But that does not seem to be happening in the following case.

BaseClass has a private member 'age'.
ExtendedClass (which extends BaseClass) has a public member 'age'.

BaseClass has a private method totalAge(), which uses the 'age' of the current object to calculate the total age of the group.

totalAge() method, always uses the 'age' value of the BaseClass, instead of the instance.
For e.g. when i created an instnce of 'ExtendedClass', and the code flows through the totalAge() method of the BaseClass, 'this.age' picks up the
value from the "BaseClass" object, even though it's an instance of the 'ExtendedClass'.

Why is this happening? Or am i doing something wrong?

Here are the three classes

**BaseClass**

```
public class BaseClass{
    public int members ;
    public String name ;
    private int age ;

    public BaseClass(int numMembs, String groupName){
      members = numMembs ;
      name = groupName ;
      if(members < 10) age = 60 ;
      else age = 25 ;
    }

    public String getName(){
       return name ;
    }


    public void printDetails(){
       System.out.println("Group Name : "+name+" Total Members: "+members+
                                       " Total Age: "+totalAge()+"\n") ; 
    }

    private int totalAge(){
       System.out.println("This object is an instance of Class: "+ this.getClass().getName()+"\n") ;
       return (this.age) * members  ;
   }
}
```

**ExtendedClass**

```
public class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass{

    public String groupLocation ; //extra member in the extended class
    public int age ; 

    public ExtendedClass(int numMembs, 
                     String groupName,
                     int age)
    {
        super(numMembs, groupName) ;
        this.age = age ; 
    }

    @Override
    public void printDetails(){
        System.out.println("Average age of the group: "+age+"\n") ;
        super.printDetails() ; //access the public method of the parent class
    }

    //Added a new method, which is not there in the parent class
    public int avgAgeOfGroup(){
        return age ;
    }
}
```

**TestBaseExtendedClasses**

```
public class TestBaseExtendedClasses {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExtendedClass extObj = new ExtendedClass(5,"Oldies", 65) ;
        BaseClass parntObj = new BaseClass(15,"YoungTurks") ;

        //Access base class methods using the extended class
        System.out.println("Group name of extObj is : "+ extObj.getName() ) ;

        //Access the overriden method in the extended class
        extObj.printDetails() ;

        //print details of parntObj
        parntObj.printDetails() ;
    }
}
```

This is the output, i got when i ran the code

**>java TestBaseExtendedClasses**

Group name of extObj is : Oldies
Average age of the group: 65

This object is an instance of Class: ExtendedClass

Group Name : Oldies Total Members: 5 Total Age: 300

This object is an instance of Class: BaseClass

Group Name : YoungTurks Total Members: 15 Total Age: 375

---

If you note, the Total Age calculation for the "Oldies" group has used 60, instead of 65. Why the baseclass used the value 60, instead of 65 (this.age, should refer to the 'age' in the extObj )?

Comment: You are hiding fields by redeclaring them in your subclass..

Comment: the printDetails() method in BaseClass is called, which eventually calls totalAge(), Since totalAge() is in BaeClass and returning (this.age * members), it is using BaseClass's age. Hence  it is 60.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `printDetails` method in the `ExtendedClass` prints out some text, then it delegates to the parent class.

When you create an instance of `ExtendedClass`, it also initializes the `BaseClass` as expected, including the setting up of the `age` field.

Going back to `printDetails` of the `ExtendedClass`, after delegating the call to the parent class, the call is once again delegated to the `totalAge` method, which uses the `age` instance it knows about (the *private one*, declared in the `BaseClass`).

In a nutshell, you need follow @Mark Rotteveel's advice and avoid hiding and playing around with variables just by providing variables with the same name.

Comment: I would agree with you and Mark Rotteveel's and i am playing with hiding the fields. But, isn't "this" keyword supposed to get the member variable of it's own instance? rather than looking at the nearest matching variable in scope?

Comment: The `totalAge` method is within the `BaseClass`. From the `BaseClass`'s perspective that is the only `age` that exists.